# Endpoint "Get analytics" returning empty response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/analytics
```

refrence:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/itemanalytics-get?view=graph-rest-beta

On trying to call this endpoint, it is returning empty as response with 200 status code.
As per documentation, it should have return something like

```
{
    "allTime": {
        "access": {
            "actionCount": 123,
            "actorCount": 89
        }
    },
    "lastSevenDays": {
        "access": {
            "actionCount": 52,
            "actorCount": 41
        }
    }
}
```

**request-id:** 67aa7bd8-6bd3-40c0-8f12-a1c4cabda4af

Answer (score 1):

Try adding /lastSevenDays or /AllTime to it and it should return the data.

```
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/analytics/lastSevenDays
GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/analytics/allTime
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue and now that endpoint is under the 1.0 ref (not beta any more)